# How can I redirect requests under a folder to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've implemented bundling in my legacy MVC project, but now all the relative paths in my CSS (which I can't change) are failing as they point to `/bundles/style/content/images` instead of `/content/images` where they used to.

How can I redirect all requests to `bundles/style/content/images` to `/content/images`?

An example of a bundle name might be:

`bundles/style/main`

Comment: Can you add some examples of the names you're using for your bundles?

Comment: @TiesonT. I've added a bundle name as example, it jumping up one level and the request is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I discovered an ItemTransformer called [CssRewriteUrlTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which rewrites urls to be absolute so assets will still be found after bundling.

Used when creating your bundle like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/style/main").Include("~/Content/styles/main.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Answer (score 1):

As [this article](http://www.mvccentral.net/Story/Details/articles/kahanu/stylebundle-403-error-solved) shows, the easiest solution is usually to just name your bundles in such a way that the compiled file name mimics the actual directory your assets are to be pulled from. For instance, if I use this bundle name:

```
~/content/css
```

Then the compiled file looks like:

```
/content/css?v=mGNb6rXCidBW01Yat0fYjijROYRAUCUgazmWOLfWJnQ1
```

Which works, since that means my relative paths start with the `/Content` directory.

The problem you're having is pretty common; enough so that the NuGet packages for, say, Bootstrap and FontAwesome actually moved their `/font` directory to the site root, since then the relative paths in their CSS actually work.

If you want actual rewrites, I think that can only be done at the IIS level; I'll do some digging and see if ASP.NET supports local rewrites (a la the `.htaccess` file you can use with PHP).

**Edit:** As usual, Scott Gu to the rescue: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @shenku It's only cheating if we get caught, right? Kidding; but yeah, until someone comes up with a better solution, this is what I do in my projects.

Comment: Just found this CssRewriteUrlTransform, adding it to your include fixes all the Urls :D eek.

Comment: If there is something specific you did to fix this, please post it as an answer,  since I'm sure we're not the only ones having this problem. It's perfectly acceptable to post and accept your own answer...

Comment: I've added my answer. Work 100% :D